# Is it true that $\operatorname{Int}(A) \cap \operatorname{Int}(B) = \operatorname{Int}(A \cap B)$?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

can someone please verify my proof?

> (a) Is it true that $\operatorname{Int}(A) \cap \operatorname{Int}(B) = \operatorname{Int}(A \cap B)$?
>
> (b) Is it true that $\bigcap \operatorname{Int}(A_\alpha) = \operatorname{Int}\left(\bigcap A_\alpha \right)$?

(a) Yes. Let $x \in \operatorname{Int}(A) \cap \operatorname{Int}(B)$. Since $x \in \operatorname{Int}(A)$, there exists a neighborhood $V_x$ of $x$ contained in $A$. Similarly, there exists a neighborhood $W_x$ of $x$ contained in $B$. Since $x \in W_x \cap V_x$, which is open and contained in $A \cap B$, $x \in \operatorname{Int}(A \cap B)$.

Let $y \in \operatorname{Int}(A \cap B)$. Then, there exists a neighborhood $U_y$ of $y$ contained in $A \cap B$. But $U_y$ is contained in each of $A$ and $B$. So, $y \in \operatorname{Int}(A)$ and $y \in \operatorname{Int}(B)$. That is, $y \in \operatorname{Int}(A \cap B)$.

Therefore, $\operatorname{Int}(A) \cap \operatorname{Int}(B) = \operatorname{Int}(A \cap B)$.

(b) No. Let $A_k = [-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}]$. Then, $\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \operatorname{Int}(A_k) = \{0\}$, while $\operatorname{Int}(\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty A_k) = \varnothing$

Comment: For (a), toward the end when you said $y \in \text{Int}(A)$ and $y \in \text{Int}(B)$, that is $y \in \text{Int}(A \cap B)$, I think what you meant to say is that $y \in \text{Int}(A)$ and $y \in \text{Int}(B)$ implies $y \in \text{Int}(A) \cap \text{Int}(B)$.  Otherwise, the proof looks great.  And also, great counterexample for (b)!

Comment: That's good, except for a typo at the end of the third line from the bottom. Also, I'd add steps to show what the interiors of the sets $A_k$ are, and what their intersection is.